# Information needed to get specific list / user group

Tags: list, custom-actions

I am working on a Custom Action that I want to add to all list instances as well as all user groups. The purpose is to export the list / group as a document to allow the user to export it when Client Integration is not enabled (it's a FBA site). I have the following XML in my elements.xml file:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
  GroupId = "ActionsMenu"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
  ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/MenuSpreadsheet.gif"
  Sequence="1000"
  Title="Export to Excel">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/LetGuide/ExportToExcel.aspx?ListId={ListId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction
  GroupId = "ActionsMenu"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.PeoplePage"
  ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/MenuSpreadsheet.gif"
  Sequence="1000"
  Title="Export to Excel">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/LetGuide/ExportToExcel.aspx?ListId={ListId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

My question is: On the receiving ASPX page, is the list ID enough for me to pull out the specific SPList instance (this might be on the root web or a sub-web - the feature is deployed at site scope)? And will it work for user groups as-is? (I am not sure if they have list IDs in the same manner as normal lists).

If anyone can point me to some sample code or documentation for how a receiving ASPX page could be created, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all you need is to read intently the following MSDN topic:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458635.aspx

You can see now, that besides of `{ListId}` token, you can also use the `{SiteUrl}` token, which will point to the URL of the current web:

> **{SiteUrl}** - URL of the Web site (SPWeb).

And SPWeb object can be retrieved easily by its url, using [SPSite.OpenWeb(url)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.openweb.aspx) method.

But actually you can even do without this token.

Since you're specifying **~site** token, the *ExportToExcel* page will be initialized with the context of the current web.

> **~site** - Web site (SPWeb) relative link.

So, you will be able to use SPContext.Current.Web or just [this.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.unsecuredlayoutspagebase.web.aspx) to get the SPWeb object, where the list is stored.

And once you've got the SPWeb object, you can grab the list using SPWeb.Lists[Guid] indexer.

The code of the Page_Load method will look something like this:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    var listGuid = new Guid(Request.Params["ListId"]);
    var list = this.Web.Lists[listGuid];
    // do whatever you need with the list
}
```